# How can I define in LESS an element that has a class of class="btn btn-primary"

Tags: css, less

I have tried all different combinations but don't seem to be able to get it right. Can someone help by telling me how I can define this in less given the starting point of:

```
.btn {


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [LESS parent selector, `&`](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature), to reference the parent selector.

```
.btn {
    &.btn-primary {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

In doing so, you are essentially selecting `.btn` elements that also have the class `.btn-primary`.

The above LESS will compile to the following:

```
.btn.btn-primary {
  color: red;
}
```